# sys_category in a powermail save data finisher

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

i want to write powermail data in the data table of an own extbase extension. the form delivers a uid of a sys_category which i want to persist in my extension.

The relevant lines in my finisher:

```
$obj = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('Vendor\myExt\Domain\Model\ProductRating');
$obj->setName('Huber');
$obj->setPrename('Hans');
// etc.
$this->persistenceManager->add($obj);
$this->persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

this works as expected, the entries are persisted in the data table. But now i want to persist the given sys_category. This:

```
$obj->setCategories(13);  // 13 is the uid of the category
```

obvviously does not work ("expected parameter of type '\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage', 'string' provided). I need to implement the ObjectStorage of sys_category but i don`t know how.

Very thankful for every hint ... !

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new instance of an ObjectStorage (e.g. $os = new ObjectStorage();) and now you can add an object to the objectStorage. After this you can use it in setCategories() function.

Answer (score 0):

The hint from Alex Kellner showed me the way.
I will describe it in detail - perhaps some will find it useful:

First inject the category repositiory:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\CategoryRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $categoryRepository;
```

then create an news objectStorage and attach the given category:

```
$newCategories = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage;
$myCategory = $this->categoryRepository->findByUid(85);
$newCategories->attach($myCategory);
```

Naturally the uid of the category should derive from the powermail form ...

This works.

Thanks Alex!